# Using scope from js file in html file

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I am having trouble about using the ng-if in my html file. I guess what I cannot figure out is how to use the variable from my js file.

Html:

```
<div ng-if="name==Michael">
do some stuff when if-statement is true
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.name = "Michael";
```

How shall I use this scope in html?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"name=='Michael'"`, add quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot about quotes:

```
<div ng-if="name=='Michael'">
do some stuff when if-statement is true
</div>
```

Comment: Wow what a simple thing to forget! Thanks for your answer. Is my usage of the scope correct apart from that small thing i missed?